# Cannot find name 'AbortSignal' during npm run build

Tags: typescript, npm, build, axios

```
node_modules/axios/index.d.ts:93:12 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AbortSignal'.

93   signal?: AbortSignal;
              ~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

When trying `npm run build` comand for node typescript project, i am getting above error, something related to axio package. before axio usage, npm run build working fine.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to add DOM to the lib array in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
"lib": [
      "es2018",
      "DOM"
    ],
```

Comment: I just downgrade axios package, now the issue resolved, can you detail about your solution, what will happen when i put above mentioned code on tsconfig.json ?

Comment: As it's just type hints nothing other than fixing your build issue. Here is the axios issue for this https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4124.  FYI upgrading to nodejs 16 will also fix it.

Comment: Updating @types/node also helps: https://github.com/serenity-js/serenity-js/issues/1223#issuecomment-1145415886

Answer (score 8):

You could also add `"skipLibCheck": true,` to your `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`.
This will ignore errors that are present in libs under node_modules

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on node.js code and don't want to introduce a dependency on `dom` in your `tsconfig.json` (incorrect in the context of backend code), use this solution instead.

`Cannot find name 'AbortSignal'.` is a regression in Axios, which has been fixed on `master`, but never released - see [Axios#4229](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/4229).

However, based on [Axios#4304 (comment)](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/4304#issuecomment-1015244291), you can see that @alecgibson updated `@types/node` module to introduce `AbortController` and `AbortSignal` in [DefinitelyTyped#58270](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/58270), to reflect its support since Node.js 14.7.0.

To address the issue in Axios, make sure to update `@types/node` to a recent `^14` release or newer.

*Solution originally posted in [Serenity/JS#1223](https://github.com/serenity-js/serenity-js/issues/1223)*

Comment: updated `@types/node` to v14 and it still doesn't work

Comment: @dragonfly02 - You'd need at least 14.7.0, but nowadays (Aug 2022) Node.js 16 is the Long-Term Support version, and it also has support for `AbortSignal`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also downgrade ts version to "typescript": "~4.8.2" on devDependencies sections in package.json file and run `npm i` again.